# Detect all networked devices' types in a home network

Tags: networking

I would like to write a software running in a networked device, i.e. PC. It can automatically detect the other network devices' types. For example, it can detect there is a PS3, a Wii, an IPad running in the same network. Any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: What kind of ideas? Any direction?

Comment: I believe UPnP is the way to go for this and I _think_ this is how the Windows Network screen does it.  I'd look into that for starters although it's not exactly a trivial implementation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems: first, detecting that a device is connected to your network and at `192.168.1.x`.  Second, somehow detecting what that device is.

The first is easy-ish to accomplish: there's discovery protocols like UPnP and Bonjour.  However, in a home networking scenario, the easiest and most reliable way to get a list of connected devices is probably to pull the DHCP reservations from your router.  You might have to scrape data from the router's HTML-based management interface—hacky as that may be—but it would work.  (If you're using .NET, consider the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to accomplish this.)

Once you have a list of IP addresses of connected devices, your next problem is to figure out what each device actually is.  This will be more challenging.  Some possibilities:

- You may be able to use the MAC address to help detect the device's vendor.  ([Here's a list.](http://www.cavebear.com/archive/cavebear/Ethernet/vendor.html))
- If you're using UPnP, you can ask the device what it is.
- Use [IP fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting) to determine what the device is.

Answer (score 0):

Couple thoughts. The broadcast IP address - 255.255.255.255 is where devices talk and say "here I am". Should be able to listen to this and find ip addresses and more. Second, if devices are assigned an IP address by a DHCP client (obviously) you can usually find a list on the dhcp device. Devices often have names, this is a higher level protocol, like windows SMB, that you may have to interface with in order to get that information.